# Shortcode: text content ends up outside html tags

Tags: shortcode

I have a shortcode which loops through a custom post type. It is supposed to output a link and a title for each post. But the result is that the divs and link tags that are created are empty, while the text content (link and title) ends up outside these wrapping divs.

Here is the code for the shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('products_info', 'get_products');

  function get_products(){
        //Loops through products
      $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1) );
        if ($loop->have_posts()):
            $output = '<div class="test01">';

            while ($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();
                $output .= '<div>
                        <a href="' . the_permalink() . '">';
                $output .= the_title() . '</a></div>';
            endwhile;
            $output .= '</div>';

        else : $output = '<div>(no products)</div>';

        endif;

        return $output;
```

}

And on the resulting page, I get:

```
<div class="entry-content">
                    http://thesite/product/theproduct/Nameoftheproduct1http://thesite/product/theproduct/Nameoftheproduct2<p>new test.<br />
    <div class="test01">
          <div><a href=""></a></div>
          <div><a href=""></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the "a href" becomes **empty**, and the link ends up in the main content div, along with the title which is "Nameoftheproduct1" and "Nameoftheproduct2".

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Note that `the_*` is usually echo's the values and `get_*` is usually returns the value. It's also custom to clean up  with `wp_reset_postdata()`..

Comment: Maybe I should use get_post and get_title then? And yes, I used reset postdata before, but wasn't sure if it was the right thing..but okay.

Comment: I just tried using "get_permalink()" and "get_the_title()" and this solved the problem!! Thanks!